# Non-Confusing Simple Validation of email in Java String

Tags: java, string, email-validation

I am trying to find a simple method to check to see if a user's input meets a couple criteria for an email address. I've read through many threads on this subject and most seem to want to validate the email address too. I'm not trying to build some super duper email address validator/checker. I'm trying to build a method that checks for these things:

1. The string entered by the user contains the '@' sign.
2. There are at least two characters before the '@' sign.
3. There is a '.' after the at sign followed by only three characters. The domain name can be as long as needed, but the string must end with "._ _ _". As in ".com" or ".net"...

I understand that this is not an all encompassing email address checker. That's not what I want though. I want just something this simple. I know that this is probably a routine question but I can't figure it out even after reading all of the seriously crazy ways of validating an email address.

This is the code I have so far: (Don't worry I already know it's pretty pathetic.... )

```
public static void checkEmail()
{
    validEmail(emailAddresses);
    if(validEmail(emailAddresses))
    {

    }
}

public static boolean validEmail(String email) {
    return email.matches("[A-Z0-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{3}");
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is simple in this case. You posted some cases (contains @, contains another chars before/after). I would read the spec and make a complete regular expression to validate it.

Comment: Just a note for terminology: You don't want to check an email, you want to check an *email address*. This is not the same.

Comment: An another note: There are top level domains with more (`museum`, `aero`) and with less than two (`de`, `us` etc. - all the country code top level domains, in fact) letters. (And most of my email addresses end with `.de`.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Thanks for the correction. I made the necessary edits to clarify the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfect, but gets the job done.

```
static boolean validEmail(String email) {
    // editing to make requirements listed
    // return email.matches("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}");
    return email.matches("[A-Z0-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{3}");
}

void checkEmails() {
    for(String email : emailAddresses) {
        if(validEmail(email)) {
             // it's a good email - do something good with it
        }
        else {
             // it's a bad email - do something... bad to it? sounds dirty...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add lower case too?

Comment: I could. I could add a lot of things. It would be as easy as changing every `A-Z` to `A-Za-Z` (and probably some shortcut I don't know could do it even better.) But, OP wanted simple, and simple he gets.

Comment: @glowcoder Thanks for the help. I'm trying to understand the email.matches part of the boolean code and I'm a little confused as to how to incorporate it into my code. I've input the boolean code into my code as a separate method. Now I'm trying to write the "if" statement. I edited the original question.

Comment: @glowcoder My question is this: will the return email.matches return 'true' if the email is valid and 'false' if email is invalid? So that the direction I'm going with the above code is correct?

Comment: @glowcoder Thanks. In the mean time I got to reading through more documentation and I found another way of doing it... Same outcome, just another way. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: What about .info, .name, .ru, .ua subdomains? There are tons of top-level domains that has other number of characters than 3.

Comment: @AndriyBohdan I would hope that minor alteration would be trivial to modify, especially considering that was in my original example.

Comment: I just want to let people know that the proposed validation won't work for people using non-3-letter TLD.

Comment: @AndriyBohdan That's alright. If you read the original post, you'll see he specifically asks for exactly 3 letters in the TLD, which is why the edit was made. But you're right, it won't work for info name or ru unless you combine it with the commented out validation above it.

Answer (score 12):

The `javax.mail` package provides a class just for this:  [`InternetAddress`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html).   Use [this constructor](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) which allows you to enforce RFC822 compliance.

Comment: Have to admit I like this better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexOfAt = email.indexOf('@');
// first check : 
if (indexOfAt < 0) { 
  // error
}

// second check :
if (indexOfAt < 2) {
  // error
}

// third check :
int indexOfLastDot = email.lastIndexOf('.');
if (indexOfLastDot < indexOfAt || indexOfLastDot != (email.length() - 4)) {
  // error
}
```

Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for the documentation of the String methods.

Comment: This allows `test@foo@bar.com` which isn't compliant. It also doesn't for characters that aren't allowed, such as `,<>\`` and their ilk.